# Date Manipulation in R using ISOdate

Tags: r, date

I'm new to R but am trying to manipulate a given date in my code that has been converted(??) into an ISOdate form.

```
datenum=ISOdate(year,month,day)
```

The year, month and day have been taken from an input file.

I would like to subtract 14 days from the date that the file represents. For example, the date of my first file is 01-12-2013 so I want to convert it to 12-29-2012. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
install.packages("lubridate")
require("lubridate")

datenum=ISOdate(2013,1,12)
# [1] "2013-01-12 12:00:00 GMT"

datenum-days(14)
# [1] "2012-12-29 12:00:00 GMT"
```